# How to change the lead layout to default layout using ANT

Tags: eclipse, ant, migration-tool, force.com-ide, git

I have a requirement to enable the default button for Lead Layout using ANT tool.

[image]

This is my **Package.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Lead-Lead Layout</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>    
    <version>39.0</version>
</Package>
```

Please help me with the MetaData for below **Lead-Lead Layout.layout** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Layout xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
.
.
.
.
.
</Layout>
```